# Freeze a Python script using Mayavi

Tags: python, pyside, py2exe, cx-freeze, mayavi

I have a script in Python with a GUI in QT (implemented through Qt designer and PySide) embedding a custom Mayavi widget.

I want to build it with cx_freeze, but I don't know if it is possible, because I wonder if I can freeze Mayavi?

Comment: As a first action I would just try it. Did you already try it?

Comment: Yes, i have already tried it, but without results.

Comment: What happened exactly? If an error message occured, could you post it?

Comment: Ok if you can kindly write me you e mail address I will send you a folder with a very simple script embedding a Mayavi obect and the setup.py file used to launch cx_Freeze.

Comment: cx_freeze does not show any error, but when a I try to run the exe file, I see this: C:\Anaconda\Lib\sie-packages\traitsui\toolkit.py, line 51 in import toolkit, no module named qt4

Comment: I have tried also with py2exe and this is the error (last line of the .log file) that appears when i double-click the exe:   File "C:\Users\Mattia\Desktop\FreezeMayavi\building-temp\.\mayavi\preferences\preference_manager.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources